# Stop checkbox being checked twice when inside an li with a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm writing a simple dropdown menu with jQuery and each item has a checkbox.  When I click on an `li` element the checkbox is selected.  However if I click on the checkbox itself, it does not select because it is effectively checked twice.  How can I stop this happening?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEp7V/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dropdown">Channels</div>
<ul class="droplist">
    <li>News <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>Sport <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>Science <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>Health <input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>All</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#dropdown {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.droplist {
    display: none;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
}

ul.droplist li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.droplist li input {
    float: right;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#dropdown").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    });

    $(".droplist li").click(function(e) {
        // Toggle the checkbox
        var input = $(this).children("input");
        $(input).prop("checked", !$(input).prop("checked"));
    });

    $(".droplist li:last").click(function () {
        // Select all boxes
        var check = $('.droplist li input:not(:checked)').length;
        $(".droplist li input").prop("checked", check);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of the event at the checkbox:

```
$(".droplist li :checkbox").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree to the parent `li` element (where, as you say, it triggers the event handler bound to it).

---

As a side note, you could modify your code to take advantange of event delegation, which is more efficient since there's only one event handler instead of one for each `li` element. For example:

```
$(".droplist").on("click", "li", function (e) {
    // Toggle the checkbox
    var input = $(this).children("input");
    $(input).prop("checked", !$(input).prop("checked"));
});
```

See the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the checkboxes with labels (labels share the browser native click event with the input)

```
<li><label for="news_input">News <input type="checkbox" id="news_input" /></label></li>
<li><label for="sport_input">Sport <input type="checkbox" id="sport_input" /></li>
<li><label for="science_input">Science <input type="checkbox" id="science_input" /></li>
<li><label for="health_input">Health <input type="checkbox" id="health_input" /></li>
```

And get rid of this behaviour

```
$(".droplist li").click(function(e) {
   // Toggle the checkbox
  var input = $(this).children("input");
  $(input).prop("checked", !$(input).prop("checked"));
});
```

Like this, you should be fine. The problem with your solution is that the native browser checkbox function and jQuery kill each other as soon as a user hits the input with a click. (Browser checks the checkbox, jQuery unchecks it)